# Download Manager Not Working in Android Oreo

Tags: android, cordova, android-download-manager, download-manager

Mine is a cordova hybrid app. I have installed [this](https://github.com/vasani-arpit/cordova-plugin-downloadmanager) plugin to download pdf files from server(url). It works fine in devices running in Android 7.0. When the same app is installed in Oreo devices, nothing happens and after some time, I see "download unsuccessful" message. What could be the reason for this?

I also upgraded a mobile where it was working previously to 8.0 and tested. It failed. So when the OS is Oreo, this is not working.

```
private void startDownload(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            String filename = message.substring(message.lastIndexOf("/")+1, message.length());
            try {
                filename = URLDecoder.decode(filename,"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                callbackContext.error("Error in converting filename");
            }
            android.app.DownloadManager downloadManager = (android.app.DownloadManager) cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);            
            Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(message);
            android.app.DownloadManager.Request request = new android.app.DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
            //Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(android.app.DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | android.app.DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            //Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            //Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
            request.setTitle(filename);
            //Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
            request.setDescription("DataSync File Download.");
            //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory            
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
            //Set visiblity after download is complete
            request.setNotificationVisibility(android.app.DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            long downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trying this in an emulator or on a  physical device?

Comment: Physical device. All the testing in physical devices

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added this permission in Menifest.xml File

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```
>
> and use the following code

```
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse(url));

    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                    url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    dm.enqueue(request);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```